# Не работает метод .hide, а метод .closest работает

Tags: jquery, методы

Есть два примера кода, 1(код в котом закоментирован метод .closest)  и 2(в котором нет коментария) в первом случае код не может применить метод .hide, а применяется только метод .closest, во втором случае оба метода работают, в чем моя ошибка, почему в первом случае не работает метод .hide?

код 1, в этом коде работает только метод .closest и не работает .hide

```js
$(".body").hide();

$(".module h1").click(function() {
  var $body = $(this).next('.body');
  //closest('.module').find('.body');
  if ($body.is(':hidden')) {
    $body.show();
  } else {
    $body.hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Collapsible Module - Take 1</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="module">
    <div class="caption clearfix">
      <h1>Module Caption</h1>
      <span class="icon-roll">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget enim id neque aliquet porttitor. Suspendisse nisl enim, nonummy ac, nonummy ut, dignissim ac, justo. Aenean imperdiet semper nibh. Vivamus ligula. In in ipsum sed neque vehicula
        rhoncus. Nam faucibus pharetra nisi. Integer at metus. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin quis eros at metus pretium elementum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="caption clearfix">
      <h1>Module Caption</h1>
      <span class="icon-roll">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget enim id neque aliquet porttitor. Suspendisse nisl enim, nonummy ac, nonummy ut, dignissim ac, justo. Aenean imperdiet semper nibh. Vivamus ligula. In in ipsum sed neque vehicula
        rhoncus. Nam faucibus pharetra nisi. Integer at metus. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin quis eros at metus pretium elementum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Код 2, в этом коде работают оба метода:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.answer').hide();
  $('.main h2').click(function() {
    var $answer = $(this).next('.answer');
    if ($answer.is(':hidden')) {
      $answer.slideDown();
      $(this).addClass('close');
    } else {
      $answer.fadeOut();
      $(this).removeClass('close');
    }
  }); // окончание click
}); // окончание ready
```

```css
h2 {
  background: url(../_images/open.png) no-repeat 0 11px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h2.close {
  background-image: url(../_images/close.png);
}

.faq {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.answer {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FAQ на одной странице</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      JAVASCRIPT <span class="amp">и</span> jQUERY: НЕДОСТАЮЩЕЕ&nbsp;РУКОВОДСТВО
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="main">
        <h1>FAQ на одной странице</h1>
        <div class="faq">
          <h2>Я слышал, что язык JavaScript — это давно потерянный источник молодости. Это правда?</h2>
          <div class="answer">
            <p>Конечно, правда! Исследования доказали, что изучение языка JavaScript освежает ум и увеличивает продолжительность жизни на несколько сотен лет. (Прим. Некоторые ученые не согласны с этими выводами)</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="faq">
          <h2>Может ли язык JavaScript решить все мои проблемы?</h2>
          <div class="answer">
            <p>Да, конечно, может! Это самый гибкий язык программирования, который может предоставить совет по управлению финансами, сделать искусственное дыхание и даже позаботиться о домашних животных.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="faq">
          <h2>Неужели нет ничего, что бы язык JavaScript был не в состоянии сделать?</h2>
          <div class="answer">
            <p>Нет! Язык JavaScript может все, включая написание раздела FAQ в соответствии с своими пиар-целями. Вот, какой умный язык программирования!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <p>JavaScript и jQuery: Недостающее Руководство, Дэвид МакФарланд.</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В рабочем примере блок, который прячется, находится непосредственно под блоком, на который кликают, поэтому `next()` срабатывает.

В нерабочем примере, за блоком, который кликают, следующей идет иконка. Для правильной работы нужна конструкция:

```
var $body = $(this).parent().next('.body');
```

Смотрите исправленный код ниже.

Конструкция с `closest()` не срабатывает в том плане, что она находит все элементы с классом `body` - несколько вместо одного, так как вы поднимаетесь вверх на две ступеньки к предкам элемента, а затем оттуда делаете полный поиск вниз командой `find`.

Следует заменить на:

```
var $body = closest('.caption').find('.body');
```

```js
$(".body").hide();

$(".module h1").click(function() {
  var $body = $(this).parent().next('.body');
  //closest('.module').find('.body');
  if ($body.is(':hidden')) {
    $body.show();
  } else {
    $body.hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Collapsible Module - Take 1</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="module">
    <div class="caption clearfix">
      <h1>Module Caption</h1>
      <span class="icon-roll">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget enim id neque aliquet porttitor. Suspendisse nisl enim, nonummy ac, nonummy ut, dignissim ac, justo. Aenean imperdiet semper nibh. Vivamus ligula. In in ipsum sed neque vehicula
        rhoncus. Nam faucibus pharetra nisi. Integer at metus. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin quis eros at metus pretium elementum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="caption clearfix">
      <h1>Module Caption</h1>
      <span class="icon-roll">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget enim id neque aliquet porttitor. Suspendisse nisl enim, nonummy ac, nonummy ut, dignissim ac, justo. Aenean imperdiet semper nibh. Vivamus ligula. In in ipsum sed neque vehicula
        rhoncus. Nam faucibus pharetra nisi. Integer at metus. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin quis eros at metus pretium elementum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```